# Error 1004 application-defined or object-defined error using vlookup?

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting this error 1004 when trying to use this vlookup. I use a window to select a file then that file is used in the vlookup. I do it in another macro I have and I used basically the same code. But for some reason this one is not working. Can anyone see any glaring issues? I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

I get the error on the First VLOOKUP formula right after the "With ws"

```
Dim iRet As Integer
Dim strPrompt As String
Dim strTitle As String
Dim shtName As String


' Prompt
strPrompt = "Please select the last Kronos Full File before the dates of this Report." & vbCrLf & _
    "For example, if the date of this report is 9-8-17, you would want to use the closest date Kronos Full File." & vbCrLf & _
    "If one was not ran in the past couple days, then run a new Kronos Full File, and then choose that file."

' Dialog's Title
strTitle = "Latest Kronos Full File"

'Display MessageBox
iRet = MsgBox(strPrompt, vbOK, strTitle)

Dim Window2 As String
Dim X As String
Dim lNewBracketLocation As Long
Dim wb2 As Workbook


Window2 = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
    FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xls*", _
    Title:="Choose the Newest Kronos Full File", MultiSelect:=False)

Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Window2, ReadOnly:=True)
shtName = wb2.Worksheets(1).name
wb2.Close

MsgBox "You selected " & Window2
'Find the last instance in the string of the path separator "\"
lNewBracketLocation = InStrRev(Window2, Application.PathSeparator)
'Edit the string to suit the VLOOKUP formula - insert "["
X = Left$(Window2, lNewBracketLocation) & "[" & Right$(Window2, Len(Window2) - lNewBracketLocation)


With ws
.Range("M2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP($K2,'" & X & "]shtName'!$B$2:$E$99999,4,0)"
.Range("N2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP($K2,'" & X & "]shtName'!$B$2:$C$99999,2,0)"
.Range("O2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP($K2,'" & X & "]shtName'!$B$2:$U$99999,20,0)"
.Range("P2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP($K2,'" & X & "]shtName'!$B$2:$Q$99999,16,0)"
.Range("Q2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP($K2,'" & X & "]shtName'!$B$2:$S$99999,18,0)"
End With
```

Comment: Are you sure x = what you think it should?

Comment: Good question I am guessing that is probably what it is, but I copied it over from my other code and those ones work. I will take another look at it.

Comment: Don't you need `.Range("M2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP($K2,'" & X & "]" & shtName & "'!$B$2:$E$99999,4,0)"` as `shtName` is a variable?

Comment: hmm yeah now when I go to debug, the shtName pops up as what the actual sheet name should be now. But I am still getting the error

Comment: ThInk as Scott says you need to check the value of X. Set a breakpoint on that line.

Comment: I am trying to see why it is wrong but I don't see anything that would be wrong about it. How do I set a breakpoint there and what does that do? I might just start from scratch on this part again with code that I know works if I can't get it...

Comment: @Robillard no! the debugger is your primary tool, learn to use it! You can toggle a breakpoint on any executable statement with F9. When you run the code, it will stop there. Then you can hit F8 to run the code line by line, use the *immediate pane* (Ctrl+G) to test things and reassign in-memory values on the fly, use the *Locals* toolwindow to view the values for everything that's currently in-scope, ... don't just wipe out your code and rewrite it, learn to use the debugger, it's fundamental!

Comment: Whoa all that is new stuff to me. I knew about f8 and going through but that is all that I knew about those parts. I will check that stuff out.

Comment: Not sure how to use the Immadiate window and the Locals Window is interesting. But it STILL is getting the same error. I don't see anything wrong still... I am just going to use the code that I know works again. I must have messed up transferring something over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like my issue had to do with the range that I was trying to use the VLOOKUP with. It looks like once I changed the 99999 to only like 9999, then it seemed like the VLOOKUP worked. I am still not sure why but I am pretty sure that was it. I got no error message when I lowered that number range. I am guessing because it was going out of the ranges of the actual worksheet or something.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go around using a `Range`'s address from another workbook, is set the range, and later on you can use `Range.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, xlExternal)`. The 4th partameter will add the name of the worksheet and workbook if necessary.

```
Dim Rng1 As Range  ' new Range Object

Window2 = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xls*", _
                                Title:="Choose the Newest Kronos Full File", MultiSelect:=False)

Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Window2, ReadOnly:=True)
'shtName = wb2.Worksheets(1).Name '<-- not necessary

Set Rng1 = wb2.Worksheets(1).Range("B2:E99999")    
wb2.Close

With ws
    .Range("M2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP($K2," & Rng1.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, xlExternal) & ",4,0)"
    ' define more ranges for the other formulas

End With
```